# How can I find out when the treeview has finished loading?

Tags: .net, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo treeview HierarchicalDataSource like this.

```
treeViewData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: getTreeData,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            //To bind child items for parent nodes
            children: "items",
            id: "NodeId"
        },
    }
});
```

How can I find out when the treeview has finished loading?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Adding to @MarcoPalma's answer, the `dataBound` function is fired as soon as the loading ends. His answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can put in your kendoTreeView Configuration event "databound" something like 
but this is Fired when the widget is bound to data from its data source.

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: treeViewData,
  dataBound: function(e) {
    //bound

  }
});
```

but probably you hant some Jquery function?

somthing like:

```
 $("#treeview").find()
```

Hope this help

Comment: Your answer is correct. When you have `dataBound`, you won't need any other separate function to grab the event, it's just there for you

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  databound is called on every item, not after the tree is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    treeview.dataSource.read().then(function () {
        //bound
    });
```

The function is called only once - when the data binding to the `TreeView` is completed. Instead of `//bound`, you need to write the code that should be executed after the end of data binding.

Comment: Please explain what your answer does.  See [answer].

Comment: Despite the fact that the question was asked for a long time, I thought that the answer to it might be useful to someone.

In the above example, the function is called only once - when the data binding to the TreeView is completed. Instead of "//bound", you need to write the code that should be executed after the end of data binding.

Comment: This should be in your answer, not in a comment.  See [answer].

Comment: Your answer will be of more value to others if you explain what it is doing and how it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 Kendo Treeview added LoadCompleted function to notify the tree is loaded completely.

```js
 loadCompleted: function (ev) {
    console.log("Load Completed: ", ev.nodes);
  }
```

The full source code

```js
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Employees",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "EmployeeId",
      hasChildren: "HasEmployees"
    }
  }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  loadOnDemand: false,
  dataSource: dataSource,
  dataTextField: "FullName",
  loadCompleted: function (ev) {
    console.log("Load Completed: ", ev.nodes);
  }
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="treeview"></div>
```